# Could not load type 'Firebase.Database.FirebaseObject`1' from assembly 'Firebase, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Building a MVC with firebase but prompt this error during runtime.
[Anyone knows how to solve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrAYF.png)

Comment: im guessing you should try installing the nuget

Comment: @TheGeneral I did installed the package

Answer (score 0):

This is simaple, your project name is Firebase and you are using:
`using Firebase.Database;`
Create new project with a different name and it would work.